# KendoUI. Virtualization for dropdown doesn't work correctly

Tags: kendo-ui, dropdown

I'm trying to make dropdown with server filtering and paging. Paging works fine, but when I begin typing filter, my control sends an infinit count of queries to the server. Please help me to configure this control.
Datasource:

```
getDataSource = function () {
        return new kendo.data.DataSource({
            type: "json",
            transport: {
                read:{
                    url:"...",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json"
                },
                parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                    switch (operation) {
                        case "read":
                            return JSON.stringify(options);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            },
            schema: {
                data: "Data",
                total: "Total",
                model: {
                    id: "Id"
                }
            },
            pageSize: 20,
            serverPaging: true,
            serverFiltering: true
        });
    }
```

options for dropdown:

```
$scope.DropDownOptions = {
        dataTextField: "Value",
        dataValueField: "Id",
        dataSource: getDataSource(),
        filter: "contains",
        virtual: {
            itemHeight: 26,
            valueMapper: function (options) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "...",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: JSON.stringify({
                        skip: 0, pageSize: 20, take: 1, filter: { logic: "and", filters: [{ value: options.value, field: "Value", operator: "contains", ignoreCase: true }] }
                    }),
                    success: function (data) {
                        options.success([]);
                    }
                })
            }
        },
        height: 290,
    }
```

and server side:

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        public DictionaryQueryResponse GetDictionary(KendoUIDropDownRequest request)
        {
            var response = new DictionaryQueryResponse();
            string filterQuery = request.filter.filters[0].value;
            var data = _client.GetDictionary(filter: filterQuery, skip: request.skip, take: request.take);
            response.Data = data;
            response.Total = 1000;
            return response;
        }
```

One more important thing:
when i change 
options.success([]) to options.success(data.Data), it still sends infinit queries, but in addition there is stratification in first item (2 same values draws in one container) and paging is slowing down. When I scroll list a little, paging normalizes

Answer (score 0):

problem solved. this strange behavior was caused by 
response.Total = 1000;
i needed to write in this field real count from database